# How do I run .jar file from Intellij IDE, built by Maven?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ I created Maven run configuration, that looks like this:

[image: Maven run configuration]

When I run it, I get .jar file:

[image: Maven .jar file]

And when I run it, I get this message:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1250 -jar D:\Projekty\Programowanie\Portfolio\java-studying\MavenHelloWorld\target\MavenHelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
no main manifest attribute, in D:\Projekty\Programowanie\Portfolio\java-studying\MavenHelloWorld\target\MavenHelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

How do I run this .jar file from intelliJ?

Comment: It does, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compile into a jar file, there's a terminal in IntelliJ to display println, just press the green start button in App.

In the future, follow these steps to create manifest and use Build>Build Artifacts>name.jar>Build to create a runnable jar file:

1. https://prnt.sc/txmlul
2. https://prnt.sc/txmp28
3. https://prnt.sc/txmsqa